# Replicate PMT function in SQL, use column values as inputs

Tags: sql

In excel the PMT function gives you a monthly payment based upon the annual rate, total number of periods, and original face value, and ending value of a bond.

The mathematical formula for calculating the monthly payment is:

```
M=[OF(i(1+i)^n)]/[(1+i)^(n-1)]

M=Monthly payment
OF=Original Face
i=annual interest rate/12
n=number of periods
```

To calculate the monthly payment with (i=.08/12, n=10, OF=10000)  as inputs, I used this:

```
if object_id('dbo.PMT') > 0
drop function dbo.PMT
go

create function dbo.PMT(@rate numeric(15,9), @periods smallint, @principal numeric(20,2) )
returns numeric (38,9)
as
begin
declare @pmt numeric (38,9)
select @pmt = @principal 
/ (power(1+@rate,@periods)-1) 
* (@rate*power(1+@rate,@periods))
return @pmt
end

go
```

Then to correct for data types, based on a forum I used:

```
drop function dbo.PMT
go
create function dbo.PMT
(
@rate float,
@periods smallint,
@principal numeric(20,2)
)
returns numeric (38,9)
as
begin
declare @pmt numeric (38,9)

declare @WK_periods float,
@WK_principal float,
@wk_One float,
@WK_power float

select  @WK_periods = @periods,
@WK_principal = @principal,
@WK_One = 1

select  @pmt =
round(
( @WK_principal * (@rate*power(@WK_One+@rate,@WK_periods)))
/ (power(@WK_One+@rate,@WK_periods)-@WK_One)
,9)

return @pmt

end
go
declare @rate float
select @rate = .0800000000000/12.000000000000000000

select PMT = dbo.PMT( @rate, 10 , 10000 )

PMT
```

This returned an accurate and correct answer. However, is there a way to do this so that instead of using these constants  (i=.08/12, n=10 etc) as inputs, I could use a column of values? I have about 10000 bonds all with different periods, rates, and original faces and need to calculate monthly payments based on their column. Ideally, I would have an additional column displaying monthly payment for each bond. Any help at all would be incredible, thanks!

Comment: are you inputs columns in a table then? Please add this and sample data if so

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    <originalcolumns>,
    dbo.PMT(M.RateColumn, M.periodsColumn, M.principalColumn)
FROM
    MyTable M
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is almost 10 years old, but I found it when Googling the same thing for BigQuery. I adapted your function code into my own BigQuery UDF. I'm dropping it here in hopes it helps the next person to stumble upon this question.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION equalMonthlyPayment(rate FLOAT64, periods INT64, principal INT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
AS (
  principal / (power(1+rate,periods)-1) * (rate*power(1+rate,periods))
);

SELECT equalMonthlyPayment(
  (0.07/12), -- 7% interest, divided over 12 months
  (30*12),   -- 30 year mortgage
  400000     -- $400k loan amount
) as monthly_payment

-- Output = 2661.209980
```

Of course, you can plug in columns as-needed in lieu of the hard-coded values.