# Loan Amortization Schedule - Need to solve for a target payment number

Tags: t-sql, excel-formula, amortization

Open to using SQL or Excel... I can generate a loan amortization schedule.  But, the problem I'm trying to solve is re-tooling the calculation such that the UNKNOWN VALUE is the payment number when a particular balance is achieved.  Typically, you are solving for principal reduction, to get the new ending balance for incremented payments 1 through n.  But I know the target unpaid balance that I'm looking for, and would like to figure out how to calculate the payment number when that balance would be achieved.

So, trying to figure out how to skip calculating every month of the amortization schedule to figure out when a target balance has been achieved, and instead back straight into the payment number from knowing the target balance.

I've figured out how to do it in SQL, very cool process, using a user-defined function for creating an amortization schedule over a portfolio of loans, with double-nested loops.  The outer loop increments through the portfolio, the inner link increments scheduled payments numbered 1 through n.  The problem is... it's going to take (est.) 61 hours to run (even after a concerted tuning effort) because the incremental looping can be very slow... IT/network folks are going to be very displeased with me.

Here's the user defined function for single use... I loop through this incrementing @payments.  But the math is over my head for figuring out how to rewrite to solve for payment number, rather than solving for @upb (unpaid principle balance).

```
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @upb AS DECIMAL(11,2) = 0    --initialize
        DECLARE @premium AS DECIMAL(11,2) = @original_unearned_premium_balance
        DECLARE @interest AS FLOAT         = @interest_rate 
        DECLARE @term AS INTEGER       = @original_term    
        DECLARE @payments AS INTEGER       = @payments_made        

        SET @upb = 
             CAST(
                   @premium * POWER(1 + @interest / 12, @payments) - 
                   ROUND((@interest / 12 * @premium) / (1 - POWER((1 + @interest / 12),(@term * -1))), 2)  * ((POWER(1 + @interest / 12, @payments) - 1) / (@interest / 12))
                AS DECIMAL(11,2))

        RETURN @upb

    END
```

Comment: You forgot to add a sample with it's expected results

Comment: Have you considered writing a recursive common table expression (CTE) that generates the entire payment schedule for a loan? (Optionally terminating at a target UPB.) A table-valued user-defined function could return the result to another query that handles multiple loans.

Comment: Have you looked at the Excel [NPER() function?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/nper-function-240535b5-6653-4d2d-bfcf-b6a38151d815)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12637193/t-n, that's a great thought, I had forgotten about that Excel fx.  I would have thought that seeding the FV factor with the target balance (it's not '0') would give me the payment number at which that would be achieved, but it does not seem to do so.  Going to keep playing, maybe I'm not employing the formula correctly.   My other consideration is that the user-defined function i shared earlier, is just an algebra problem.  If I know UPB, I should be able to solve for the @payments variable.

Comment: You can start with `=NPER(0.01, -1000, 50000, -40000, 0)` as an example and play with the numbers. This reflects a 1% periodic (perhaps monthly) interest rate (`rate`), a $1000 payment (`pmt`), a $50000 starting balance (`pv`), a $40000 ending balance (`fv`), and payments made at the end of each period (`type = 0`).  The `NPER()` result is 18.32 periods, which reflects about half of the payments being offset by interest.  The fact that `fv` is negative seems odd. Perhaps it can be thought of as the balloon payment needed to close out the loan.

Comment: [This Q&A page](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=58261) has some discussions. It seems that in finance, the relationships are defined by `PV (1+RATE)^NPER + PMT * (1+RATE * type) [ { (1+RATE)^NPER } - 1 ] / RATE + FV = 0` or `FV (1+RATE)^-NPER + PMT * (1+RATE * type) [ 1 - { (1+RATE)^-NPER } ] / RATE + PV = 0`.  If you set PMT, RATE, AND NPER all to zero, this reduces to `PV + FV = 0`, which means `FV = -PV` in the absence of activity. Seems unintuitive to me, but I guess it must make sense to the finance experts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12637193/t-n, THAT's IT.... the FV has to be negative!!!   I am now getting the correct result!  Thank you so much!!!  Will also take a look at the Q&A page and your subsequent response... ideally, I want to recreate the amortization calc in SQL so that I can automate this process rather than having to pull it into Excel and do it manually, but for the moment, any solution is viable!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION IDENTIFIED...

Replicate the Excel PMT and NPER functions in SQL; PMT is a component of the NPER function.  NPER is going to give you number of payments remaining based on a current balance, interest rate and payment, so for my purposes, I needed to derive a result from Original Term (known value) less NPER result, to identify when that particular balance would be reached.

PMT fx - [Replicate PMT function in SQL, use column values as inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194957/replicate-pmt-function-in-sql-use-column-values-as-inputs)

NPER fx - provided in T-N comment above.

Thanks for the suggestion about NPER, T-N... it triggered my thinking to find the PMT function to solve this exercise.  Was able to run an entire ETD portfolio in < 1 min.